# Using cv2.resize() on an image array allows me to hash it without converting to bytes

Tags: python, opencv

hashlib.md5() can't take an ndarray as a parameter so I have to use .tobytes() to convert the ndarray to bytes. If I don't do this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

However, if I use cv2.resize() on the ndarray, I am able to hash it without converting to bytes even though the output of cv2.resize() is still an ndarray:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("img.png")
r_img = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)
print(type(r_img))
```

gives the output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Here is my full code:

```
import timeit
import cv2
import hashlib

image = cv2.imread("img.png")


def hash_without_resize(img):
    b_img = img.tobytes()
    return hashlib.md5(b_img).hexdigest()


def hash_with_resize(img):
# Resize the image with scale factor 1 in both directions (the image stays exactly the same)
    r_img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=1, fy=1)
    return hashlib.md5(r_img).hexdigest()


print(timeit.timeit('hash_without_resize(image)', 'from __main__ import hash_without_resize, image', number=1000)
print(timeit.timeit('hash_with_resize(image)', 'from __main__ import hash_with_resize, image', number=1000)
print(hash_without_resize(image), hash_with_resize(image))
```

giving the output:

```
0.4001011
0.40305579999999985
62da8968d9cb37790811ff16624d8cc7 62da8968d9cb37790811ff16624d8cc7
```

As you can see, no error is thrown when hashing the resized ndarray despite it still being an ndarray. Also, the hashes are the same so the image isn't changed by the resize at all. Could someone explain why this is happening because I'm very confused. It also works when using cv2.flip() and other opencv functions. I also tried this with other hash functions and got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get for the original image already says it all:

```
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

The hash function only works on contiguous areas of memory, but ndarrays (and Python buffers in general) can be non-contiguous. Many functions which create a new ndarray will create it as contiguous, so you could always use one of these functions to get a hashable ndarray.

However, you should be aware that hashes on images are rarely useful except when you want to identify pixel-exact copies. As soon as the image has been modified even very slightly, for example by compressing as jpeg and uncompressing, it has a completely different hash, even if it looks identical.